$a^2 = 3^b + 37$
Find all solutions in integers to $a^2 = 3^b + 37$.
I came up with this problem myself. (I chose $37$ so there would be a relatively large solution.)
But is there a nice way to approach this problem? I got that $a$ must be divisible by $4$ and that $b$ must be odd, but I couldn't progress past this. I tried making a substitution out of this, saying that $a = 4x$ and $b = 2y + 1$ but I couldn't quite get this to work.
For reference, Wolfram Alpha says there are four solutions:
(a, b) = (8, 3); (-8, 3); (3788, 15); (-3788, 15)

Working backwards from the solutions, it would appear that $b\equiv 3\mod 12$ is a starting point.  What sort of answer are you hoping for, knowing that WA seems to suggest there are only four solutions?

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the fairly similar Finding positive integer solutions to $3^x + 55=y^2$, but the exponent there must be even, so the solution involves a product of the difference of squares equaling $55$, so it's considerably simpler. In some ways, a more similar type question to yours is Perhaps a Pell type equation, where the exponent is odd like in your case. Solving it as a Pell's equation is suggested, but ...

(cont.) the one solution there instead uses elliptic curves, or Mordell equations.

Let $y=3^m$ & $b=3m+r$, where r=0,1,2 it reduces to $3^r ×y^m +37=a^2$ is an elliptic curve. You need to find all Integer points for this elliptic curve. By Siegel theorem: If an Elliptic curve has a nonzero discriminant then Number of integer points of an Elliptic Curve is finite.

These kind of equations are called Ramanujan - Nagell type Equations

There is a typo in my 1st comment in 3rd line. It should be :$a^2=3^r × y^3+37$

from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

def find_values():
    results = []
    getcontext().prec = 1000  # Set precision high enough
    for b in range(1, 1000, 2):  # b must be odd, so we step by 2
        value = Decimal(3)**b + 37
        a = int(value.sqrt())
        if a % 4 == 0 and a**2 == value:
            results.append((a, b))
    return results

values = find_values()
for a, b in values:
    print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}")

if not values:
    print("No values found.")

a = 8, b = 3
a = 3788, b = 15

I think that [a = 8, b = 3] , [a = 3788, b = 15] (and it's negative values for a) are only that work for that sequence
code only gives positive values !

Comment: Starting from the solutions you found we may try to pridict the existence of more solutions. We may manipulate like this:
$3^b+3^3=a^2-10\Rightarrow a^2-10\geq 27$
In the case $a^2=27$ we have:
$27=3^b\Rightarrow b=3$
Which gives $(a, b)=(8, 3)$
We may also say $3\mid a^2-37$ and a is even. For searching we write:
$a=8, 10, 12, 14, 16\cdot\cdot 28\cdot\cdot\cdot$
$a^2= 64, 100, 144, 256, \cdot\cdot\cdot784$
then try to find a sequence or a progression, for example take $64$ as the first number of a progression:
$100=64+4\times 9$
$196=54+4\times 33$
$256=64+4\times 48$
$\cdot$
$\cdot$
$\cdot$
$724=64+4\times 165$
$\cdot$
$\cdot$
$\cdot$
$3788^2=64+ 4\times 3587220$
Now in the progression formula $N= a+n \cdot d$ we have $a=64$ and $d=4$ and we have to find a relation between n and N. $n$ is not the number of term or elements but it has the following sequence:
$9, 33, 48, 84, 108, 153, 165, \cdot\cdot\cdot 3587220\cdot\cdot\cdot \infty $
The number $3587220$  gives $a^2= 64+4\times 3587220=3788^2$ which gives $(a, b)(3788, 15)=15$.
That means more solutions are probable as Kodzis found in his second post.
